# Static Inner class instantiation - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, static, classnotfoundexception, inner-classes

I have the following class in a jar

```
public class Loc {

 public static class Dat {
     private int x, y;

     public Dat(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
     }
  }
}
```

In another project, I am instantiating the above class like this: (I am importing the above class)

```
Loc.Dat data = new Loc.Dat(19,10);
```

But I see the following error in the log. (doesn't show in the tomcat server console)

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/myservice] 
         threw  exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is 
           java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/company/manage/serv/Loc$Dat] 
           with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.company.manage.serv.Loc$Dat
```

I went into WebApps folder and opened the jar file. I see the Loc and Loc$Dat class files.

What am I missing?

Edit:
I forgot to say that this compiles fine. No errors shown. It shows only when I run it.

Answer (score 2):

> In another project, I am instantiating the above class

This sounds like you are probably trying to create an instance from within another package.

The visibility of the inner class can't exceed the the outer class' visibility. `Loc` is not public, so you can't import `Dat` inside another package.

Comment: Loc is Public. Edited the post.